# Require user to enter password to delete Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to (some dialog maybe?) that can require a user to enter his password for Facebook, in order to confirm his identity (again)...

I have a webpage, which is using Facebook login. But I would like to require the user to enter his password in order to delete his membership of the page.

Comment: This would be a question for the facebook developer forum, not here.  Or, maybe the facebook stackoverflow page (facebook.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Wug: The facebook.SO site isn't a separate site. It's just a filtered view of SO. See here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14224289/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to handle this. If you have them enter a password for your site after they login via fb, then you can build a simple confirmation yourself.

*And my personal opinion:* Just use a captcha to prevent a bot from doing it. Besides that, until your site becomes "big enough" to get attention, its not as big of a really a security hole as you're probably thinking it is. If it would be *disastrous* for them to lose membership, then users should probably have a separate password for that website anyway. And if you're still stuck on this idea, just do what Facebook does: don't actually "delete" the user, just move it into an "inactive" state. If they come back, make it all "active" again.